# Trying to center or float wrapper div with 100% width

Tags: html, css, css-float

I'm not sure how to get the following main div to center on the page with 100% width or to even float to the left at least, how can I do this?

http://jsfiddle.net/d36TC/6/

```
<div class="addInput"><div sytle="clear:both"></div>        
    <input class="input"  type="text" name="func_name"/>
        <b class="addText">Name of Function: </b>
</div>      

<div class="addInput">
    <input class="input"  type="text" name="func_location"/>
        <b class="addText">Location: </b>
</div>  

<div class="addInput">
    <input class="input"  type="text" name="func_date"/>
        <b class="addText">Date: </b>
</div>      

<div class="addInput">
    <input class="input"  type="text" name="func_timein"/>
        <b class="addText">Time In: </b>
</div>      

<div class="addInput">
    <input class="input"  type="text" name="func_timeout"/>
        <b class="addText">Time Out: </b>
</div>      

<div class="addInput">
    <input class="input"  type="text" name="AECap"/>
        <b class="addText">Adult Ed Pos.: </b>
</div>          

<div class="addInput">
    <input class="input"  type="text" name="SCCap"/>
        <b class="addText">Cook Pos.: </b>
</div>          

<div class="addInput">
    <input class="input"  type="text" name="WSCap"/>
        <b class="addText">Wait Staff Pos.: </b>
</div>          

<div class="addInput">
    <input class="input"  type="text" name="JTCap"/>
        <b class="addText">Jr. Training Pos.: </b>
</div>
```

Comment: If its width is 100% then horizontal alignment is irrelevant; left, right, and centre will all be exactly the same. Do you mean you want to align the div's content in the centre?

Comment: I want each input field and respective text on a new line and I want it to expand to 100% of the screen, but unfortunately the text keeps dropping down to the next line because my input boxes are at a width of 100%

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this...

```
    .input
{
    height:30px;
    float:right;
    box-shadow:inset 0 1px 6px #000000;
    width:85%;
}

.addInput {
    float:left;
    width:100%;
}

.addText {
    line-height:30px;
    height:30px;
    float:left;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/bowenac/gsN93/

Comment: That's better, guess I will just have to reduce the percent size of the input box for mobile phones

Comment: If you add your b text above the inputs you can float them both left. Then you could create two separate media queries one for desktop res and mobile res and change the css width % for each.

Comment: Here is an example, not sure how well this works in jsfiddle but should work for mobile etc you will get the idea. http://jsfiddle.net/bowenac/gsN93/1/

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you want? I added another div to wrap around the form elements:

```
<div style="margin:0 auto; width:450px;">
```

http://jsfiddle.net/d36TC/4/

Comment: Eh, I really want it to be dynamic, I updated the jsfiddle code and it shows how the text drops down within each div but I want the text to be to the left of each input box and I want each 'addInput' div to expand across the browser 100%.

Answer (score 0):

Does this accomplish what you're looking for?

```
.addText {
width: 13%;
line-height:30px;
height:30px;
float: left;
margin: 0 1% 0 0;
```

}

http://jsfiddle.net/dustinhorn/Kf89p/